# How replace file_get_contents with Zend_Http_Client ?(differnce in encoding etc..)

Tags: php, zend-framework, file-get-contents, zend-http-client

How replace file_get_contents with Zend_Http_Client ?(differnce in encoding etc..)

**code that should be replaced:**

```
$url='http://google.com';$timeout=60;
$t = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('timeout' => $timeout)));
$content = @file_get_contents($url,0,$t);
```

**My Solution:**

```
$url='http://google.com';$timeout=60;
$client = new Zend_Http_Client($url, array('timeout' => $timeout));
$content=$client->request()->getBody();
```

please do you have better solution, does my solution have weak parts?

---

Edit:Improved solution

```
function getResponse($url='http://google.com',$timeout=60){
    $client = new Zend_Http_Client($url, array('timeout' => $timeout));
    if($content->isError())    {
            return null;
    }
    return $content->getBody();
 }
```

Remark: event better can be use of curl adapter that doing work much faster.

Thanks,
Yosef

Comment: something is missing... I think "$content=$client->request()->getBody();" before the if ($Content bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ok. You can also check what the response code is and act based on that. You can get codes like 500, 404 or 403 in some cases.

Comment: Which code do you suggest to add?maybe its better to check which response code succees like 200 etc.. because theoreticly exist much more failed response code? see my edit please

Comment: @Yosef: Yes, I'd reverse the check to only return the body on success status codes (ie. 2xx).

Comment: isSuccess check only 2.. not 3.. that also could be good, soo I use isError that check 4.. + 5.. responsed status

Comment: Depends on your use case. You can set the redirections using `$config = array(
'adapter'   => 'Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Curl',
'curloptions' => array(CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true),
);` as constructor param ;)